# Assigning data from a fitted regression model to a new column results in error: Assigned data must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to plot my linear-mixed effect model with ggplot2, but I struggle to plot the individual data points.

Because I have included pre-test as a covariate in the model, and there were some differences between conditional means at the pre-test, the estimated means from the model are quite different from the sample means. It is best to illustrate this with a test figure:

[image: testplot]

Now, I want to plot the adjusted values of the individual data points, but I struggle to implement this in R. I found a related question ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49757/plotting-a-model-in-r)), so I tried to use the fitted() function but get an error message:

```
CI_post <- lmer(
  post.diff ~ 
    pre.diff +
    group * course 
  + (1|bib) 
  + (1|school), 
  data = dat, 
  REML = FALSE)

dat$fitted <- fitted(CI_post)

#########
Error: Assigned data `fitted(CI_post)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 156 rows.
x Assigned data has 154 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Impute or remove missings in `dat`. There are two obs deleted in the regression, which is the reason it doesn't fit.

Comment: Does this help? https://garthtarr.github.io/meatR/emmeans.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because there were missing values that were dropped when the model was fit. So the fitted values contain 2 less than the data, hence the error. I reproduced this with some fake data.

```
> nrow(data)
[1] 32
> nrow(fitted_values)
[1] 30
> data$fitted = fitted_values$fitted.fit.
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, fitted, value = c(20.4094804918911,  : 
  replacement has 30 rows, data has 32
```

To get around this, you can either remove the observations that were dropped by the model, or left join the original data on the fitted values (which will drop the observations not in that set).

```
fitted_values = left_join(x = fitted_values,
                          y = data,
                          by = c("car"))
> head(fitted_values[, 1:5])
  fitted.fit.               car  mpg cyl disp
1    20.40948         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160
2    20.16342     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160
3    26.89532        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108
4    19.10009    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258
5    14.99109 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360
6    18.75736           Valiant 18.1   6  225
```

Then add those points to the plot.

```
  ... +
  geom_point(data = fitted_values,
             aes(x = factor(cyl),
                 y = fitted.fit.),
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))
```

Which yields the following plot where there are 2 less fitted values than original data. The fitted values are in black and the original data is in color.

[image]